# How to set environ variables in local development with virtualenv

Tags: python, django, apache, amazon-web-services, wsgi

I am currently trying to publish via ZIP my django app to an AWS elasticbeanstalk.

As I have a local and online development enviroment I would like to make use of the environ variables, that are used anyways by AWS.

For my development environments I am already using virtualenv. Apache runs with wsgi enabled and is supposed to use such environments. Unfortunately, it does not know the environ that I have set in the bin/activate.

Django throws a 500 error, since it cannot connect to the database as it does not have access to the environ vars:

```
1:53.862779 2015] [wsgi:error] [pid 20639] [remote 127.0.0.1:51896] KeyError: 'RDS_DB_NAME'
```

If I activate my env and look into the env vars:

```
(myenv)[bs@debian-gohan:]/var/www/vhosts/mysite $ env | grep RDS
RDS_HOSTNAME=localhost
```

... and I get the others as well...

My Apache Vhost is:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    WSGIDaemonProcess mysite python-path=/home/bs/envs/myenv/bin/python2.7:/home/bs/envs/myenv/lib/python2.7/site-packages
    WSGIProcessGroup mysite
    WSGIScriptAlias / /var/www/vhosts/main-page/mysite/wsgi.py
```

Does anyone have an idea why the environ vars are not seen by the apache ?

**EDIT 1:**
I have tried to use SetEnv in the Apache config, like this:

```
SetEnv RDS_HOSTNAME "localhost"
```

Unfortunately, this did not work. I then removed the ProcessGroup and only used a simple WSGIPythonPath. That did not work either.

The error in the apache log remains the same:

```
[Thu Mar 26 11:30:34.046807 2015] [wsgi:info] [pid 23012] [client 127.0.0.1:55231] mod_wsgi (pid=23012, process='', application='mysite.dbz.dev|'): Loading WSGI script '/var/www/vhosts/main-page/mysite/wsgi.py'.
[Thu Mar 26 11:30:34.178717 2015] [wsgi:error] [pid 23012] [client 127.0.0.1:55231] mod_wsgi (pid=23012): Target WSGI script '/var/www/vhosts/main-page/mysite/wsgi.py' cannot be loaded as Python module.
[Thu Mar 26 11:30:34.178812 2015] [wsgi:error] [pid 23012] [client 127.0.0.1:55231] mod_wsgi (pid=23012): Exception occurred processing WSGI script '/var/www/vhosts/main-page/mysite/wsgi.py'.
[Thu Mar 26 11:30:34.178924 2015] [wsgi:error] [pid 23012] [client 127.0.0.1:55231] Traceback (most recent call last):
[Thu Mar 26 11:30:34.178947 2015] [wsgi:error] [pid 23012] [client 127.0.0.1:55231]   File "/var/www/vhosts/main-page/mysite/wsgi.py", line 17, in <module>
[Thu Mar 26 11:30:34.179111 2015] [wsgi:error] [pid 23012] [client 127.0.0.1:55231]     application = get_wsgi_application()
[Thu Mar 26 11:30:34.179157 2015] [wsgi:error] [pid 23012] [client 127.0.0.1:55231]   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/wsgi.py", line 14, in get_wsgi_application
[Thu Mar 26 11:30:34.179319 2015] [wsgi:error] [pid 23012] [client 127.0.0.1:55231]     django.setup()
[Thu Mar 26 11:30:34.179363 2015] [wsgi:error] [pid 23012] [client 127.0.0.1:55231]   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/__init__.py", line 20, in setup
[Thu Mar 26 11:30:34.179606 2015] [wsgi:error] [pid 23012] [client 127.0.0.1:55231]     configure_logging(settings.LOGGING_CONFIG, settings.LOGGING)
[Thu Mar 26 11:30:34.179651 2015] [wsgi:error] [pid 23012] [client 127.0.0.1:55231]   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 46, in __getattr__
[Thu Mar 26 11:30:34.179774 2015] [wsgi:error] [pid 23012] [client 127.0.0.1:55231]     self._setup(name)
[Thu Mar 26 11:30:34.179789 2015] [wsgi:error] [pid 23012] [client 127.0.0.1:55231]   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 42, in _setup
[Thu Mar 26 11:30:34.179918 2015] [wsgi:error] [pid 23012] [client 127.0.0.1:55231]     self._wrapped = Settings(settings_module)
[Thu Mar 26 11:30:34.179959 2015] [wsgi:error] [pid 23012] [client 127.0.0.1:55231]   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 94, in __init__
[Thu Mar 26 11:30:34.180072 2015] [wsgi:error] [pid 23012] [client 127.0.0.1:55231]     mod = importlib.import_module(self.SETTINGS_MODULE)
[Thu Mar 26 11:30:34.180112 2015] [wsgi:error] [pid 23012] [client 127.0.0.1:55231]   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/importlib/__init__.py", line 37, in import_module
[Thu Mar 26 11:30:34.180220 2015] [wsgi:error] [pid 23012] [client 127.0.0.1:55231]     __import__(name)
[Thu Mar 26 11:30:34.180246 2015] [wsgi:error] [pid 23012] [client 127.0.0.1:55231]   File "/var/www/vhosts/main-page/mysite/../mysite/settings.py", line 94, in <module>
[Thu Mar 26 11:30:34.180400 2015] [wsgi:error] [pid 23012] [client 127.0.0.1:55231]     'NAME': os.environ['RDS_DB_NAME'],
[Thu Mar 26 11:30:34.180443 2015] [wsgi:error] [pid 23012] [client 127.0.0.1:55231]   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/UserDict.py", line 23, in __getitem__
[Thu Mar 26 11:30:34.180613 2015] [wsgi:error] [pid 23012] [client 127.0.0.1:55231]     raise KeyError(key)
[Thu Mar 26 11:30:34.180665 2015] [wsgi:error] [pid 23012] [client 127.0.0.1:55231] KeyError: 'RDS_DB_NAME'
```

Comment: I'm not sure I understand where you are setting these vars. virtualenv is about containing Python paths, and doesn't usually have anything to do with env vars more generally.

Answer (score 0):

Set like this

```
<VirtualHost hostname:80>
   ...
   SetEnv VARIABLE_NAME variable_value
   ...
</VirtualHost>
```

**In wsgi script.**

```
os.environ.setdefault("variable", "value")
```

To override variable,

```
os.environ['var']="val"
```

Comment: SetEnv only sets per request WSGI environ variables for mod_wsgi, not process level environment variables.

Comment: Thank you @Graham Dumpleton, you gave the right point to make me rethink about the problem. I solved it by creating a new wsgi.py file that is loaded by my development Apache vhost. I just used os.environ and set the vars myself in the wsgi file. ! Great!

Comment: Setting the process environment variables in the WSGI script file is the best way.

Comment: @GrahamDumpleton How does one do this?

Comment: @JZ. you can simply set env variable by `os.environ.setdefault("variable", "value")` in wsgi script. or to override variable `os.environ['var']="val"`